# Port restrictions and MACs

Tags: ipv4, dhcp, mac-address

I have a question regarding connections within a university setting. In my room I have two network points. One for my pc and one for my voip phone. Each network port is restricted to one mac address, switches and hubs are blocked.

Is it possible to connect three devices using only two ports, without the use of hubs, switches or routers? For example I would like to have two pcs and one voip phone.

Each device on the network must have it's mac address registered and is assigned an ip via dhcp.

I know it's possible to spoof mac addresses of registered devices on to non registered devices etc.

I appreciate the help and apologies if this is a silly question!

Comment: You cannot connect via WiFi?

Comment: I can but i would need a dongle for the second pc obviously, and performance would be an issue. Thx for the suggestion tho.

Comment: You could give the the MAC address of a small layer 3 NAT/PAT router/switch to register to that port but they may be able to tell that it belongs to a networking device vs an endpoint.

Comment: Yea they will block it straight away unfortunately.

Comment: Just connect via WiFi.

Comment: Not really an option as the second additional pc is a server and performance is important.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you find this a great community to contribute to and learn from. Unfortunately, questions by end users of a service provider network are considered off topic by this community. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. You could try posting this on a different site on the network, such as [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 1):

Install a second Ethernet NIC card on the machine that has wired network access.  This NIC card can be setup with services such as DHCP server and default gateway with PAT to enable other devices behind it wired network access.